# R: Interaction Plot with a continuous and a categorical variable for a GLMM (lme4)

Tags: r, plot, interaction, lme4, mixed-models

I would like to make an interaction plot to visually display the difference or similarity in slopes of interaction of a categorical variable (4 levels) and a standardized continuous variable from the results of a regression model.

`with(GLMModel, interaction.plot(continuous.var, categorical.var, response.var))`
Is not what I am looking for.  It produces a plot in which the slope changes for each value of the continuous variable.  I'm looking to make a plot with constant slopes as in the following plot:

[image]

Any ideas?

I fit a model of the form `fit<-glmer(resp.var ~ cont.var*cat.var + (1|rand.eff) , data = sample.data , poisson)`
Here is some sample data:

```
structure(list(cat.var = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), cont.var = c(-0.0682900527296927, 
0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, -0.887770685486005, 0.136580105459385, 
0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, -0.682900527296927, 
0.136580105459385, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, 
0.341450263648464, 0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.478030369107849, -0.478030369107849, -0.682900527296927, -0.682900527296927, 
0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, -0.0682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, 
0.136580105459385, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, 
-0.887770685486005, 0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, 0.341450263648464, 
-0.682900527296927, -0.478030369107849, 0.341450263648464, -0.478030369107849, 
0.546320421837542, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 
0.546320421837542, -0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.887770685486005, 0.136580105459385, -0.887770685486005, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.546320421837542, 0.75119058002662, 0.136580105459385, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, 0.75119058002662, -0.682900527296927, 
0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, 
0.136580105459385, 0.341450263648464, 0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.682900527296927, -0.887770685486005, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.136580105459385, -0.0682900527296927, -0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, 
0.341450263648464, 0.75119058002662, -0.682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.887770685486005, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, 
-0.887770685486005, 0.341450263648464, 0.75119058002662, -0.887770685486005, 
0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, 0.136580105459385, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, 0.341450263648464, 
0.136580105459385, -0.0682900527296927, -0.478030369107849, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, 0.75119058002662, 
0.341450263648464, 0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, 
-0.887770685486005, -0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, -0.682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.546320421837542, 0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, 0.136580105459385, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, 0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.0682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, -0.0682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, -0.887770685486005, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.682900527296927, -0.478030369107849, -0.478030369107849, -0.682900527296927, 
0.75119058002662, 0.341450263648464, -0.0682900527296927, 0.341450263648464, 
-0.0682900527296927, -0.887770685486005, -0.887770685486005, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.0682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, -0.0682900527296927, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, 
0.341450263648464, 0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, 
0.136580105459385, 0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, 0.341450263648464, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, 0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.341450263648464, 0.546320421837542, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.682900527296927, -0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.0682900527296927, -0.887770685486005, -0.887770685486005, 
0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, 
0.546320421837542, -0.0682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, 
0.546320421837542, 0.341450263648464, -0.0682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.0682900527296927, -0.887770685486005, 0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, 0.341450263648464, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, 
0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, 
0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, -0.0682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, -0.887770685486005, 
-0.887770685486005, 0.546320421837542, -0.682900527296927, -0.887770685486005, 
0.136580105459385, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, 
0.136580105459385, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, -0.682900527296927, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, 0.546320421837542, -0.682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, -0.682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, -0.887770685486005, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.0682900527296927, -0.273160210918771, -0.887770685486005, 
0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, 
0.341450263648464, 0.136580105459385, 0.136580105459385, 0.75119058002662, 
0.136580105459385, -0.0682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.887770685486005, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.887770685486005, -0.0682900527296927, -0.682900527296927, 
-0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, 
0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, 0.75119058002662, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.546320421837542, -0.0682900527296927, -0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, 
0.75119058002662, -0.0682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, -0.682900527296927, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.0682900527296927, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, 
0.546320421837542, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, 0.341450263648464, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, 0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, 
0.136580105459385, 0.136580105459385, -0.682900527296927, 0.341450263648464, 
0.341450263648464, -0.273160210918771, -0.682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.75119058002662, -0.887770685486005, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.478030369107849, -0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, 
0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, 0.341450263648464, -0.478030369107849, 
0.75119058002662, 0.136580105459385, 0.341450263648464, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.887770685486005, 0.75119058002662, 0.341450263648464, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.546320421837542, 0.136580105459385, -0.682900527296927, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.341450263648464, -0.478030369107849, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, -0.0682900527296927, 0.341450263648464, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, -0.478030369107849, -0.682900527296927, 
0.341450263648464, -0.887770685486005, -0.478030369107849, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.887770685486005, -0.478030369107849, -0.478030369107849, 0.341450263648464, 
0.75119058002662, -0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, 
0.341450263648464, -0.0682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.136580105459385, 0.136580105459385, 0.136580105459385, 0.136580105459385, 
0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, -0.0682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, 
-0.0682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, -0.682900527296927, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.682900527296927, -0.478030369107849, 0.136580105459385, 
0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, 0.341450263648464, -0.887770685486005, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, 0.341450263648464, -0.478030369107849, 
-0.0682900527296927, -0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.478030369107849, -0.0682900527296927, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.0682900527296927, -0.478030369107849, 
0.75119058002662, -0.0682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, 0.546320421837542, 
0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.478030369107849, -0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.682900527296927, -0.682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, 0.341450263648464, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, 0.136580105459385, -0.887770685486005, 
0.341450263648464, 0.341450263648464, 0.546320421837542, -0.273160210918771, 
0.136580105459385, 0.75119058002662, -0.0682900527296927, -0.682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, -0.478030369107849, 0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.478030369107849, 0.546320421837542, 0.136580105459385, -0.887770685486005, 
0.75119058002662, -0.0682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, 0.75119058002662, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.682900527296927, 0.546320421837542, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.887770685486005, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.0682900527296927, 0.136580105459385, 0.341450263648464, -0.478030369107849, 
0.136580105459385, 0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, 0.546320421837542, 
-0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, -0.273160210918771, 0.75119058002662, 
-0.887770685486005, -0.887770685486005, -0.0682900527296927, 
-0.478030369107849, -0.0682900527296927, 0.75119058002662, -0.273160210918771, 
0.136580105459385, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, 
0.75119058002662, 0.546320421837542, -0.478030369107849, -0.273160210918771, 
-0.273160210918771, 0.136580105459385, -0.273160210918771, -0.0682900527296927, 
0.75119058002662, 0.136580105459385), resp.var = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L), rand.eff = c(37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L)), .Names = c("cat.var", 
"cont.var", "resp.var", "rand.eff"), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: not too hard by combining `predict` with `ggplot` or `lattice::xyplot`.  Reproducible example please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an answer of sorts (by the way, you had some missing quotation marks in your data frame above, which had to be fixed manually ...)

Fit the model:

```
library(lme4)
fit <- glmer(resp.var ~ cont.var:cat.var + (1|rand.eff) ,
           data = sample.data , poisson)
```

(Note that this is a slightly weird model specification -- forces all categories to have the same value at `cont.var==0`.  Did you mean `cont.var*cat.var`?

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_update(theme_bw())  ## set white rather than gray background
```

Quick and dirty linear regressions:

```
ggplot(sample.data,aes(cont.var,resp.var,linetype=cat.var))+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE)
```

Now with a Poisson GLM (but not incorporating the random effect), and showing the data points:

```
ggplot(sample.data,aes(cont.var,resp.var,colour=cat.var))+
    stat_sum(aes(size=..n..),alpha=0.5)+
    geom_smooth(method="glm",family="poisson")
```

The next bit requires the development (r-forge) version of `lme4`, which has a `predict` method:

Set up data frame for prediction:

```
predframe <- with(sample.data,
                  expand.grid(cat.var=levels(cat.var),
                              cont.var=seq(min(cont.var),
                              max(cont.var),length=51)))
```

Predict at population level (`REform=NA`), on the linear predictor (logit) scale (this is the only way you will get straight lines on the plot)

```
predframe$pred.logit <- predict(fit,newdata=predframe,REform=NA)

minmaxvals <- range(sample.data$cont.var)

ggplot(predframe,aes(cont.var,pred.logit,linetype=cat.var))+geom_line()+
    geom_point(data=subset(predframe,cont.var %in% minmaxvals),
               aes(shape=cat.var))
```

[image]
Now on the response scale:

```
predframe$pred <- predict(fit,newdata=predframe,REform=NA,type="response")
ggplot(predframe,aes(cont.var,pred,linetype=cat.var))+geom_line()+
    geom_point(data=subset(predframe,cont.var %in% minmaxvals),
               aes(shape=cat.var))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the missing quotes.  I used dput, and didn't modify the output, to provided the sample data.  Should I have done something else.  And yes, you are right, I should have used `*` instead of `:` in specifying the model.

Comment: It's all a little confusing, but I would try `install.packages("lme4",repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos")` -- the build on the main r-forge repository is broken at the moment (you can always re-install from CRAN if necessary).

Comment: Anything but Excel :-) : what are the symptoms of your inability to install?  (What OS and R version are you using?)

Answer (score 3):

The `jtools` package ([CRAN link](https://cran.r-project.org/package=jtools)) can make the plotting of this sort of model pretty straightforward. I'm the developer of that package.

We will fit the model like Ben did in his answer:

```
library(lme4)
fit <- glmer(resp.var ~ cont.var:cat.var + (1 | rand.eff),
             data = sample.data, family = poisson)
```

And with `jtools` we just use the `interact_plot` function like this:

```
library(jtools)
interact_plot(fit, pred = cont.var, modx = cat.var)
```

The result:

[image]

By default it plots on the response scale, but you can have it plotted on the linear scale with the `outcome.scale = "link"` argument (default is `"response"`).

Comment: I get a loong list of warnings when trying to install jtools, posted a bit of such: 
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The date in the certificate is invalid or has expired'
cannot open URL 'https://mirror.its.dal.ca/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
I unable to access index for repository https://mirror.its.dal.ca/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://mirror.its.dal.ca/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
  package ‘jtools’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The date in the certificate is invalid or has expired'

Answer (score 1):

The [effects](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) package has support for `lme4` models, and should be able to do what you want.

> effects: Effect Displays for Linear, Generalized Linear, and Other Models
>
> Graphical and tabular effect displays, e.g., of interactions, for various statistical models with linear predictors.

It also comes with two slightly outdated [papers](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/effects/index.html) (you can think of them as vignettes).